# class 'Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider' not found error in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, adldap

I want to add Ldap authentication for my Laravel 5.5 Application. I have add ldap providers,

`'providers' => [
    ...
    Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
    Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider::class,
]`,

`'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class,
]`,

when I run command (php artisan vendor:publish --tag="adldap") or (php artisan serve) cmd show this error.
Please help me to solve this error.
my php version is 7.1.10

Comment: Try performing a php artisan clear-compiled and try again. Also ensure you've inserted the Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class, into your config/app.php.

Comment: yes, I tryed to php artisan clear-compiled but it showes same error

Comment: Also include above class into the config/app.php file?

Comment: try only without the --tag `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: No need to add them to `app.php`, Laravel 5.5 will autodiscover, you could just remove them and publish the configuration file

Comment: Thank you Darshan Jain. I solved my issue. my composer is not updated properly. Exactly error is in my php.ini file. Thank for All